# How would I find the angle and minimum initial velocity of a projectile, given the target location and target angle?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

A similar question has been asked many times, but my question is a bit different because I know the angle at which I need the projectile to land, and where, but I want to solve for the initial velocity and initial angle. [image: Landing angle problem]
Specifically, I need it to land at 30 degrees, and I need to solve for $\theta$ and $v_0$.

Here's what I have so far:

- I have the equation for the angle:$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v^2\pm\sqrt{v^4-g(gx^2+2yv^2}}{gx}\right)$$

  - I know the discriminant $v^4-g(gx^2+2yv^2$ must be near zero in order to minimize $v_0$.
- I know the derivative of the parabola should be $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ at $x$, but that doesn't help me as my variables are $\theta$ and $v_0$, so differentiating and solving for $v$ and $\theta$ won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations for projectile motion work just as well when time runs backwards. So, pretend you are launching the projectile from your target towards the origin. Since you already know the landing angle, make this the launch angle and find the speed that makes the projectile land at the origin (now you only have one variable to solve for). Calculate the velocity vector of the projectile when it hits the origin. Reversing the direction of this vector is the launch velocity vector that solves your original problem.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll give it a try. Thanks!